# Can only access one Redis Docker in network

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, redis-cluster

I'm trying to set up a redis cluster running each node on a dedicated container, but I'm having trouble connecting the containers with each other.

I'm using a docker-compose to set them up:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-cluster-master_a:
    container_name: redis-cluster-master_a
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.master_a
    volumes:
      - /docker_volumes/redis-cluster_data-master_a:/data
    ports: 
      - 7000:7000
    networks: 
      - redis-network

  redis-cluster-master_b:
    container_name: redis-cluster-master_b
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.master_b
    volumes:
      - /docker_volumes/redis-cluster_data-master_b:/data
    ports: 
      - 7001:7001
    networks: 
      - redis-network

  redis-cluster-master_c:
    container_name: redis-cluster-master_c
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.master_c
    volumes:
      - /docker_volumes/redis-cluster_data-master_c:/data
    ports: 
      - 7002:7002
    networks: 
      - redis-network
    
  redis-cluster-slave_a1:
    container_name: redis-cluster-slave_a1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.slave_ax
    volumes:
      - /docker_volumes/redis-cluster_data-slave_a1:/data
    ports: 
      - 7010:7010
    networks: 
      - redis-network

  redis-cluster-slave_b1:
    container_name: redis-cluster-slave_b1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.slave_bx
    volumes:
      - /docker_volumes/redis-cluster_data-slave_b1:/data
    ports: 
      - 7011:7011
    networks: 
      - redis-network
    
  redis-cluster-slave_c1:
    container_name: redis-cluster-slave_c1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.slave_cx
    volumes:
      - /docker_volumes/redis-cluster_data-slave_c1:/data
    ports: 
      - 7012:7012
    networks: 
      - redis-network
        

networks:
  redis-network:
```

A Dockerfile looks like that:

```
FROM redis
COPY ./conf/redis-conf-master_a/master_a.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

As you can see, redis server is running in each of those containers and they are connected via a dedicated network. I can get the IP address of a container from inspect and connect via the redis-cli to the master_a container.

```
redis-cli -h 172.21.0.7 -p 7000
```

So far, so good. But When I'm trying to connect to, let's say, master_b I get a a connection refused:

```
redis-cli -h 172.21.0.4 -p 7001
Could not connect to Redis at 172.21.0.4:7001: Connection refused
```

And because I can only connect to one container, I can not set up my cluster.

---

### Edit 1

Content of master_a.conf

```
# only listen to connections from specified hosts
# bind localhost
# accept connections on this port
port 7000 
# 'no' in order to accept connections from other hosts  
protected-mode no

# enable cluster mode
cluster-enabled yes 
# specifies timeout in ms at which node is considered as failed
cluster-node-timeout 5000 
# define the name of the nods's config file
cluster-config-file nodes-master_a.conf
# define location of logfile
logfile "" 

### PERSISTANCE ###
# enable AOF persistence
appendonly yes 
# define name of AOF file
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"  
# update AOF file after every query; other options are 'everysec' and 'no' (let the OS decide when it wants to flush)
appendfsync always 
# 'yes' to block fsync during incoming write commands in order to increase latency
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no  
# if AOF file size grows by 100% (with respect to the size after the last write command), create a new one 
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
# specify the minimum AOF file size for the file to be rewritten 
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb 

# create snapshot after 900s if 1 key changed
save 900 1 
# create snapshot after 300s if 10 keys changed
save 300 10 
save 60 10000
# define name of RDB file
dbfilename dump.rdb 

# 'no' in order to prevent Redis from stopping if an error occurs while trying to write to disk
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no 
# define the location of the RDB & AOF file
# dir /docker_volumes/redis-cluster_data-master_a

### REPLICATION ###
# 'yes' in order to allow node to send (potential) out-of-sync data in case the connection to master node is lost
replica-serve-stale-data no 
replica-read-only yes 
# defines sync strategy of replicas (via a RDB file written on disk or network)
repl-diskless-sync no 

### SECURITY ###
# set password for master node authentication
masterauth *** 
# required in order to be able authenticate to master node
requirepass ***
```

---

### Edit 2

I checked the container processes of the containers I cannot connect with from the outside, e.g. master_b:

```
docker container top redis-cluster-master_b
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
systemd+            489115              489061              0                   06:38               ?                   00:00:01            redis-server localhost:7001 [cluster]
root                489570              489061              0                   06:42               pts/0               00:00:00            bash
```

And from inside the container I can run redis-cli without any problems... So the server inside the fishy containers is running correctly...

Comment: can you share the content of `master_a.conf`?

Comment: What tells the Redises what port to listen on?  How does `b` know that it should use port 7001?  Does it work to use port 7000 instead for all inter-container connections and as the second port in all of the `ports:`?

Comment: The listen-port is defined in each .conf file. So e.g. master_b listens to port 7001 of the container, which points to 7001 of localhost

Comment: why not simply using the default image and simply remap the default port? e.g. `- 7000:6379`, `- 7001:6379`, `- 7002:6379`

Comment: @Stefano Right now I'm running the 6 nodes on localhost with basically the exact same configs. I originally changed the default ports for the sake of convenience: having ports 7000-7009 for master nodes and 7010 upwards for slaves is easier to remember. You are righ in that regardt: it is completely unnecessary to change the internal port of the Docker container. However, it shouldn't make a difference over which port I'd like to communicate...

Comment: ...And I'm baking the conf files into the container for which I need the Dockerfiles. Could also mount the conf files as a volume, but again... it shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Can you make sure all master container are up and redis process is running inside? If so, exec into the container and try to connect server from localhost to verify server works fine,

Comment: Redis server is running... see Edit 2